# String capturing and print the next characters.

Tags: ksh

I have tried few options but that not working on my case. My requirement is..
Suppose I have a parameter in a file and wanted to capture the details as below and run a shell script(ksh).

```
PARAMETR=aname1:7,aname2:5
```

The parameter contains 2 values delimited by a comma and each value separated by a colon.

So, wanted to process it as if the string matched as `aname1` then print both in different variable `$v1=aname1` and `$v2=7`. The same applies to the other value too if string searched as `aname2` then `$v1=aname2` and `$v2=5`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will do what you're asking for

```
    #!/bin/ksh

    typeset -A valueArray

    PARAMETR=aname1:7,aname2:5

    paramArray=(${PARAMETR//,/ })

    for ((i=0;i<=${#paramArray[@]};i++)); do
            valueArray[${paramArray[$i]%:*}]=${paramArray[$i]#*:}
    done

    for j in ${!valueArray[@]}; do
            print "$j = ${valueArray[$j]}"
    done
```

Hope it can help

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is helpful.

Comment: `IFS=, read -A paramArray <<< "$PARAMETER"` would be better than relying on an unquoted parameter expansion to create the array.

Comment: Similarly, `for x in "${paramArray[@]}"; do IFS=: read -r name value <<< "$x"; valueArray[$name]=$value; done` would be a little cleaner.

Comment: @chepner, Maybe, but as a general rule I never use IFS as it is a special variable used by the shell internally. I understand it can be useful sometimes, but in my experience it creates more problem than it solved in more complex script. My idiosyncrasy though.

Comment: Well, yes, I'm using it exactly as it is intended to be used. Note I'm not changing the value globally; I'm changing it just for the `read` command so it performs the desired field splitting.

Answer (score 0):

First split the line in two sets and than process each set.

```
echo "${PARAMETR}" | tr "," "\n" | while IFS=: read -r v1 v2; do
  echo "v1=$v1 and v2=$v2"
  done
```

Result:

```
v1=aname1 and v2=7
v1=aname2 and v2=5
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is also helpful.